# call the same function on many events

Tags: jquery

i need to call the same function on many events

```
$("#test1").click(function(){
some_function();
});
$("#test1").hover(function(){
some_function();
})
```

how can i write this with one function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put all the events in an array, and for each element add your function.

Example:

```
events=[ $("#test1").click, $("#test1").hover ];

for ( e in events ) {
  e( some_function );
};
```

Answer (score 4):

That seems messy.  I believe this should work.

```
$('#test1').bind('click mouseenter mouseleave', some_function);
```

Remember that `.hover()` takes two functions as arguments, so having only one function could produce unexpected results.

Comment: I would like to add you can use `event.type` (http://api.jquery.com/event.type/) to figure out which event was fired.

Answer (score 1):

$('#test1').bind('click hover', function() {
  some_function();
});

http://api.jquery.com/bind/